# Does pandas reindex `method` kwag not work with columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying this simple operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
df.columns = df.columns * 3
print(df.reindex(columns=np.arange(9), method='ffill').head())
```

And I get this:

```
          0   1   2         3   4   5         6   7   8
0  0.593936 NaN NaN  0.805081 NaN NaN  0.930780 NaN NaN
1  0.019330 NaN NaN  0.095645 NaN NaN  0.667744 NaN NaN
2  0.826164 NaN NaN  0.295915 NaN NaN  0.259967 NaN NaN
3  0.495695 NaN NaN  0.403194 NaN NaN  0.122684 NaN NaN
4  0.365294 NaN NaN  0.648194 NaN NaN  0.621820 NaN NaN
```

But, of course, I expect to see this:

```
           0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8
0   0.593936    0.593936    0.593936    0.805081    0.805081    0.805081    0.930780    0.930780    0.930780
1   0.019330    0.019330    0.019330    0.095645    0.095645    0.095645    0.667744    0.667744    0.667744
2   0.826164    0.826164    0.826164    0.295915    0.295915    0.295915    0.259967    0.259967    0.259967
3   0.495695    0.495695    0.495695    0.403194    0.403194    0.403194    0.122684    0.122684    0.122684
4   0.365294    0.365294    0.365294    0.648194    0.648194    0.648194    0.621820    0.621820    0.621820
```

I can achieve my goal with a battery of `.fillna` and slicing, but is there something more elegant? (Note, I am using pandas 0.18.1)

Comment: I think you mean `df.reindex(columns=np.arange(15)).ffill(axis = 1)`? the axis has to be specified explicitly otherwise it will `ffill` along columns.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that `ffill` was a separate `DataFrame` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this three column data frame,

```
df

#          0           3           6
#0  0.563483    0.404885    0.336098
#1  0.097173    0.141343    0.564055
#2  0.715131    0.185852    0.361714
#3  0.841248    0.028190    0.754315
#4  0.475066    0.592953    0.839101
```

To expand the columns and forward fill along rows, you can `reindex` the columns firstly and then `ffill()` with `axis = 1` to specify the fill direction to be along rows:

```
df.reindex(columns=np.arange(15)).ffill(axis = 1)

#          0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11         12           13          14
#0  0.563483    0.563483    0.563483    0.404885    0.404885    0.404885    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098    0.336098
#1  0.097173    0.097173    0.097173    0.141343    0.141343    0.141343    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055    0.564055
#2  0.715131    0.715131    0.715131    0.185852    0.185852    0.185852    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714    0.361714
#3  0.841248    0.841248    0.841248    0.028190    0.028190    0.028190    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315    0.754315
#4  0.475066    0.475066    0.475066    0.592953    0.592953    0.592953    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101    0.839101
```